# What is happening inside of this subscribe method in Angular Tour of Heroes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, subscribe

I have not been able to solve what is happening inside of this `.subscribe` method.

```
 getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
        .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
```

I always thought that `this.heroes = heroes` was being assigned to `heroes:Hero[]` inside of the heroes component. Well it turns out that is not the case. If I change `heroes:Hero[]` to `heroes:boolean` or even if I delete `heroes:Hero[]` entirely from the heroes component, **my heroes still get displayed. And `this.heroes` still gets assigned.**

Can someone please explain how this is happening?

[Here is the live example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aaldojlqqlvd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts)

Try doing the things I mentioned and deleting `heroes:Hero[]` and notice how the heroes still get displayed. If `this.heroes = heroes` is not being assigned to `heroes:Hero[]` then what is happening exactly inside of the subscribe method?

Comment: It's assigning the heroes you got from the service to the heroes property of the class. `heroes: Hero[]` is purely TypeScript, it doesn't exist at runtime. JavaScript doesn't care whether you assign to arbitrary properties, or whether you assign the "right" types; *that's why TypeScript exists*.

Comment: Inside `HeroesComponent` `this.heroes` represents the `heroes: Hero[]` from `HeroesComponent`. In `getHeroes` method, you are getting all heroes from the `HeroService` and then assigning the result to the heroes list of the component through `this.heroes = heroes`.

Comment: youri, is it possible that `this.heroes = heroes` is not assigning to the heroes list from the heroes component, but is instead assigning itself to the method parameter of `(heroes)` and then is displaying the observable that it retrieved from the hero.service in the method parameter?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, doesn't that defeat the purpose of TypeScript if it is going to be simply overrun? I don't understand why in this instance it was overrun, but in many others typescript would not allow me to compile if all the types did not match.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the `heroes` property, on getting the data from service, it is automatically creating a property in Javascript and displaying it. The browser runs the Javascript code, so there is no error. You will TypeScript compile time error if you do not declare a property or datatype of the property is incorrect

Comment: I am deleting `heroes:Hero[]` with VS code and it is still compiling, how is that possible? If I assign heroes to a boolean like this `heroes:boolean` the code still compiles and displays my heroes list. Is it possible that the .subscribe method is not being assigned to `heroes:Hero[]` and instead is assigning itself to the parameter of the method? In this case  `heroes => this.heroes = heroes` is assigning to the parameter inside the function from `hero.service` and is ignoring` heroes:Hero[] ` entirely?

Comment: Install TSLint Extension in VS code, you will see red underlines. Try building the app by `ng build --prod`, you will get error. In browser, javescript code is executed, so there is no error as for javascipt these are not any issues. Please read Difference between javascript and typescript

Comment: Adrita, is it possible that `this.heroes = heroes` is not assigning to the heroes list from the heroes component, but is instead assigning itself to the method parameter of `(heroes)` and then is displaying the observable that it retrieved from the hero.service in the method parameter? There would be no need for a `heroes:Hero[]` in the heroes component if that was the case.

Comment: No @Ne0, that's not happening over here

Answer (score 1):

> I always thought that this.heroes = heroes was being assigned to heroes:Hero[] inside of the heroes component

Correctly.
The thing is, those errors underlined in red are TypeScript errors. If somehow TS compiler gets around them and builds the project anyway, then JavaScript has no problem with, say, creating a new object property on the fly.

A production build should fail, though.

Comment: I am deleting `heroes:Hero[]` with VS code and it is still compiling, how is that possible? If I assign heroes to a boolean like this `heroes:boolean` the code still compiles and displays my heroes list. Is it possible that the .subscribe method is not being assigned to `heroes:Hero[]` and instead is assigning itself to the parameter of the method? In this case  `heroes => this.heroes = heroes` is assigning to the parameter inside the function from `hero.service` and is ignoring` heroes:Hero[] ` entirely?

Comment: No. First, the observer is an arrow function, it doesn't have its own `this`, it takes the lexical `this`, so its `this` is `HeroesComponent`. And second, the view does still display the list of heroes, doesn't it? It takes the heroes from `HeroesComponent.heroes` property.

Comment: How come if you change `heroes:Hero[]` to `heroes:boolean` in the heroes component,  `this.heroes = heroes` is still getting assigned? You can try it in the live example from stackblitz and it will still work. How is that possible?

Comment: Asked and answered.

Answer (score 1):

Here `this.heroes = heroes` where this.heores is the empty variable assigned in the top to save the data getting from the subscriber(heroes). If you didn't assign the empty variable, it will throw an error when are using this.heores. Error will throw like 'Property 'heroes' does not exist on type 'HeroesComponent'

Answer (score 1):

When you are removing `heroes: Hero[];` it will still display because it all compiles down to JavaScript from the TypeScript.

To easily visualise this in a simpler example, it would be very similar to the following, adding to the object without assigning it first.

```js
var exampleObj = {};

exampleObj.heroes = 'batman';

console.log(exampleObj);
```

This is fine in JavaScript and this is why you list is still displayed, however this is not valid TypeScript and will cause compilation errors.

> If I change heroes:Hero[] to heroes:boolean or even if I delete heroes:Hero[] entirely from the heroes component, my heroes still get displayed. And this.heroes still gets assigned.

So this means it displays because it is added to the class as soon as you define it from within the subscription.

Valid JavaScript, Yes.

Valid TypeScript, No.

---

[This documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-typescript-and-javascript/) may help high light some of the difference